# Code to DB failed with connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to design simple code that generates DB:

```
namespace CodeFirstDemo
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name ="BlogDbContext" connectionString ="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=CodeFirstDemo; integrated security==SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>    
</configuration>
```

After I have performed `enable-migrations` I got error:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 57.
```

I suppose something is wrong with my connection string:

```
<add name ="BlogDbContext" connectionString ="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=CodeFirstDemo; integrated security==SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But what exactly is wrong there?

Comment: You have == after integrated security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s an extra equal sign after “integrated security”.